# Spherical tensor operators relation to spin operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, spherical-harmonics

I am reading a research paper discussing theoretical calculations of electron paramagnetic resonance parameters (EPR)*.
In the section about higher-order EPR parameters, it states that according to the irreducible tensor operator decomposition, the dipole moment operator can be written:
$$\tag{1}
\hat{\mu}_{(l)}^{u}=\sum_{m=-l}^{l} b_{l, m}^{u} \mathcal{T}_{l, m}(\hat{\mathscr{S}})
$$
Where $\hat{\mu}_{(l)}^{u}$ is the component of the dipole moment operator in direction $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathcal{T}_{l m}$ the tesseral combinations of the spherical tensor operators 
$T_{l, m}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal{T}_{l, m}(\hat{\mathscr{S}})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[(-1)^{m} T_{l, m}(\hat{\mathscr{S}})+T_{l,-m}(\hat{\mathscr{S}})\right]\\
&\mathcal{T}_{l,-m}(\hat{\mathscr{S}})=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\left[(-1)^{m+1} T_{l, m}(\hat{\mathscr{S}})+T_{l,-m}(\hat{\mathscr{S}})\right]
\end{aligned}\tag{2}
$$
For $l=1$ we obtain from $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$\tag{3}
\hat{\mu}_{(1)}^{u}=b_{1,1}^{u} \hat{\mathscr{S}}_{x}+b_{1,-1}^{u} \hat{\mathscr{S}}_{y}+b_{1,0}^{u} \hat{\mathscr{S}}_{z}
$$
However, I lack the mathematical/physics knowledge to see how eq. $(3)$ results from the other two and hope that someone can explain this to a non-expert.

*https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02483183/document

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical harmonics in cartesian coordinates, where $e^{\pm i \phi}\sin{\theta} = ( x \pm i y)/r$ and $\cos{\theta} = z$?

Comment: I only just brushed over it in introductory quantum mechanics a couple of years ago, but I can read up on it.
Btw, I am not looking for a mathematically rigorous 'proof'. I am simply looking for the concepts/main points for understanding how eq. (3) is obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very handy to look at spherical harmonics when learning about spherical tensors. The reason is this: spherical harmonics are the eigen functions of the angular momentum operator (in the quantum view), meaning they are the standing wave solutions to waves on a sphere (in the classical view), and those are easy to visualize.

Meanwhile, spherical tensors (not quantum operators, just regular complex linear combinations of regular cartesian tensors), are eigen-tensors of rotations.

Ignoring normalization factors, the eigenvectors of a rotation by $\phi$ about the $z$-axis in the standard cartesian basis $(\hat x, \hat y, \hat z)$ are:

$$ \hat e^0 = \hat z $$
$$ \hat e^{\pm} \propto \hat x \pm i\hat y $$

and the eigenvalues for $\hat e^m$ are $\exp{(\pm im\phi)}$.

In the rank-2 case, you can verify that the dyadic products:

$$ \hat e^{\pm}\hat e^{\pm} \propto (\hat x \pm i\hat y)(\hat x \pm i\hat y) = \hat x\hat x - \hat y\hat y \pm i(\hat x\hat y + \hat y \hat x)$$

are Eigen-dyads of said rotation with eigenvalue $\exp{(\pm im\phi)}$ with $m=\pm 2$. For $m=0$ and $m=\pm 1$, the combinations are exactly what you would expect from Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

This correspondence works for any rank $l$, where there are $2l+1$ eigentensors with eigenvalues $m \in (-l, -l+1, \cdots, l-1, +l)$ corresponding the $2(l+1)$ independent values in a symmetric, traceless, rank-$l$ cartesian tensor.

The tesseral spherical harmonics are real combinations of the standard complex spherical harmonics, which for rank-1 works out as:

$$ Y_1^{+1} + Y_1^{-1} \propto [e^{i\phi}+e^{i\phi}]\sin{(\theta)} \propto \cos{\theta}\sin{\phi} = x$$

$$ Y_1^{+1} - Y_1^{-1} \propto [e^{i\phi}-e^{i\phi}]\sin{(\theta)} \propto \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi} = y$$

$$ Y_1^0 \propto \cos{\theta} = z $$

Compare with your equation (2).

The tesseral tensor operators in this case are just the cartesian vector operators, so that equation (3) is an expression of:

$$ \vec{\bf  b} \cdot  {\bf \hat{\mathscr{S}}} = b_x\hat{\mathscr{S}}_{x} + b_y\hat{\mathscr{S}}_{y} + b_z\hat{\mathscr{S}}_{z} $$

$$=b_{1,1}^{u} \hat{\mathscr{S}}_{x}+b_{1,-1}^{u} +\hat{\mathscr{S}}_{y}+b_{1,0}^{u} \hat{\mathscr{S}}_{z} $$